# Ordenar um array multidimensional por uma coluna, mantendo as mesmas linhas do array

Tags: php, array-multidimensional, classificação

Tenho um array com duas colunas, onde na primeira coluna tenho o nome de uma estação, e na segunda tenho o endereço da mesma.

Preciso ordenar esse array por ordem alfabética do nome da estação, sem perder o endereço associado!

Tentei a função `array_multisort()`, porém só consigo ordenar as colunas separadamente. Vocês podem me ajudar?

Este foi o código utilizado, com base na documentação da função `array_multisort()`. A mesma retorna o vetor "$data" ainda fora de ordem, e os vetores "$sites" e "$IPs" estão vazios.

```
            $data = array( 'sites' => $lista_estacoes, 'IPs' => $lista_enderecos);

            foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
                    $sites[$key] = $row['sites'];
                    $IPs[$key] = $row['IPs'];
            }

            array_multisort($sites, SORT_DESC, $IPs, SORT_ASC, $data);
```

Onde "`$lista_estacoes`" e "`$lista_enderecos`" são os vetores contendo os dados das estações. Algum erro que eu não esteja percebendo?

O array "`$data`" está assim:

```
 Array
 (
     [sites] => Array
         (
        [0] => 

        [1] => PrimeiraEstacao

        [2] => SegundaEstacao

        [3] => TerceiraEstacao

        [4] => 

        [5] => QuintaEstacao

...
         )

     [IPs] => Array
         (
        [0] => 

        [1] => 172.168.0.11

        [2] => 172.168.0.12

        [3] => 172.168.0.13

        [4] => 172.168.0.14

        [5] => 172.168.0.15

...
         )
 )
```

Comment: Cara da uma olhada na documentação do array_multisort acredito que o Example #3 Sorting database results seja seu caso

Comment: @AdirKuhn, obrigado! editei a pergunta acrescentando o código feito com base na documentação, que ainda não faz a ordenação. Consegue encontrar algum erro?

Comment: mostra como esta é o conteúdo do seu array

Comment: @AdirKuhn Ele tem 730 linhas, algo específico na composição do mesmo?

Analisando-o, encontrei alguns valores nulos na coluna 'sites', isso pode interferir na função?

Comment: Em teoria não, mas posta um pequeno pedaço desse array para ver a estrutura dele

Comment: @AdirKuhn, editado com um pedaço do array.

Answer (score 1):

Uma possível solução é agrupar os valores dois a dois antes de ordenar:

```
$arr = array_map(null, $arr["sites"], $arr["IPs"]);
```

Fazer a ordenação conforme o índice zero, referente à coluna `sites`:

```
usort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]);
});
```

Após, retornar a lista de valores separando os pares utilizando`array_column`:

```
return [
    "sites" => array_column($arr, 0),
    "IPs"   => array_column($arr, 1)
];
```

Ou seja, a função que faz a ordenação desejada ficaria:

```
function order ($arr)
{
    $arr = array_map(null, $arr["sites"], $arr["IPs"]);

    usort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]);
    });

    return [
        "sites" => array_column($arr, 0),
        "IPs"   => array_column($arr, 1)
    ];
}
```

Para uma entrada de teste igual a:

```
$data = Array(
    'sites' => Array(
        0 => '',
        1 => '5 Estacao',
        2 => '3 Estacao',
        3 => '4 Estacao',
        4 => '1 Estacao',
        5 => '2 Estacao',
    ),
    'IPs' => Array(
        0 => '',
        1 => '172.168.0.15',
        2 => '172.168.0.13',
        3 => '172.168.0.14',
        4 => '172.168.0.11',
        5 => '172.168.0.12',
    )
);
```

A saída gerada por `print_r(order($data))` será:

```
Array
(
    [sites] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 1 Estacao
            [2] => 2 Estacao
            [3] => 3 Estacao
            [4] => 4 Estacao
            [5] => 5 Estacao
        )

    [IPs] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 172.168.0.11
            [2] => 172.168.0.12
            [3] => 172.168.0.13
            [4] => 172.168.0.14
            [5] => 172.168.0.15
        )
)
```

Que é exatamente a lista de entrada, ordenada pelo nome do site, sem perder a ordem dos IPs.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/zgiD6J).

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrayTeste = Array(
    'sites' => Array(
        0 => '',
        1 => '5 Estacao',
        2 => '3 Estacao',
        3 => '4 Estacao',
        4 => '1 Estacao',
        5 => '2 Estacao',
    ),
    'IPs' => Array(
        0 => '',
        1 => '172.168.0.15',
        2 => '172.168.0.13',
        3 => '172.168.0.14',
        4 => '172.168.0.11',
        5 => '172.168.0.12',
    )
);
```

Primeiramente eu sugiro unificar os dados:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($arrayTeste['sites'] as $k => $value){
    $newArray[$k] = array(
        'name' => $value,
        'ip'   => $arrayTeste['IPs'][$k],
    );
}
```

Apos com esta função você realiza o Sort:

```
function arraySort($array, $on, $order=SORT_ASC){
    $new_array = array();
    $sortable_array = array();

    if (count($array) > 0) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
                    if ($k2 == $on) {
                        $sortable_array[$k] = $v2;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $sortable_array[$k] = $v;
            }
        }

        switch ($order) {
            case SORT_ASC:
                asort($sortable_array);
            break;
            case SORT_DESC:
                arsort($sortable_array);
            break;
        }

        foreach ($sortable_array as $k => $v) {
            $new_array[$k] = $array[$k];
        }
    }

    return $new_array;
}

$newArray = arraySort($newArray, 'name');
```

Out :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [ip] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => 1 Estacao
            [ip] => 172.168.0.11
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => 2 Estacao
            [ip] => 172.168.0.12
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => 3 Estacao
            [ip] => 172.168.0.13
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => 4 Estacao
            [ip] => 172.168.0.14
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 5 Estacao
            [ip] => 172.168.0.15
        )

)
```

Answer (score -1):

Já experimentou utilizar o `usort`? Ordene antes de criar seu `$data`.

```
function cmpSites($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a["sites"], $b["sites"]);
}

function cmpIPs($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a["IPs"], $b["IPs"]);
}

usort($lista_estacoes, "cmpSites");
usort($lista_enderecos, "cmpIps");

$data = array( 'sites' => $lista_estacoes, 'IPs' => $lista_enderecos);
```

### [Exemplo IdeOne](http://ideone.com/IWy6Ce)

Comment: Maicon, esse código ordena os endereços de IP separadamente, perdendo-se do nome da estação correspondente a ele., logo não resolve.  Preciso que os nomes sejam ordenados, mas que os endereços IP correspondentes os acompanhem, de modo que ambos permaneçam na mesma posição! Por isso estou tentando colocá-los em um array multidimensional.

Answer (score -1):

Experimente utilizar o método `array_map()`:

```
$data = array(
         'sites' => $lista_estacoes,
         'IPs' => $lista_enderecos
         );

          $new_data = array_map($data['sites'], $data['IPs']);

usort($new_data);

print_r($new_data);
```